# Apache Proxy CORS on end server being down or timing out

Tags: apache, proxy, cors

I am using angularjs on the UI and it cant tell the difference between the server being down or a timeout both respond with something like the following. This is due to cors. When server is down or a request times out apache does not add the cors header.

```
"{"data":null,"status":0,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"url":"https://api.domain.com/containers/60539","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}},"statusText":""}"
```

How can I make sure that I get the proper 502/503 statuses back from apache on the GET request while having 200 on the options?

Thank you!

Current Config:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName api.domain.com
  <IfModule proxy_module>
    ProxyRequests Off
    SSLProxyEngine On
    SSLProxyVerify none 
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
    ProxyPass / 1.1.1.1
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
    Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
  </IfModule>
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile "${WILDCARDSSLCRT}"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "${WILDCARDSSLKEY}"
  SSLCertificateChainFile "${WILDCARDSSLCHAIN}"
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `Header set` use `Header always set`:

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html#Header explains:

> The table that corresponds to `always` is **used for locally generated error responses as well as successful responses**.

---

And a couple of guides with some good guidance:

- [Getting CORS to work with Apache](https://awesometoast.com/cors/)
- [Setting CORS (cross-origin resource sharing) on Apache with correct response headers allowing everything through](https://benjaminhorn.io/code/setting-cors-cross-origin-resource-sharing-on-apache-with-correct-response-headers-allowing-everything-through/)

Comment: Worked almost perfectly, as the server apache called was also returning cors headers I needed to do unset and then set. Might be worth noting in case someone else comes across this.

Thank you!